# Best way to save date data and results on PARSE using SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I'm new to programming, and I'm making my first app. The idea is that the user adds a value of his weight and a date. The values are stored and graphed so the user can see how his weight changes over time.

I only know how to use PARSE, so I'm planning on storing the data using the info as an array on PARSE, something like
["day","month","year","wheight","any coments"]

But I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, so that latter I can order the results and graph them. I'm using swift.

I get the date using a UIDatePicker and I want to split the date to comparate and order it before making the graph, so I'm turning each part of the date into an NSString.

I get the results I need, but I'm not sure if I'm thinking of the most efficient way to store them, ¿what are your thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to have a structure like this:

A class(`PFObject`) called `Weight` with the properties:

- `user` of type `Pointer<PFuser>`
- `weight` or type `Number`
- `date` of  type `Date`

This is the basic structure and will allow you to do what you need.

The comparison you're doing should be done using the "real" types you need, for instance you shouldn't compare dates as strings. You can make it work but it is not recommended since you can compare dates natively.